# Create a bookmark in firefox by coding,not Manually

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Yeah,I use FireFox and IE9.0+,sometimes,Chrome.

Chrome always takes much RAM usage but it is faster.
IE10 which i am using is much faster than before,but because of my win7 os,I can't sync nothing simply.
So,I like FireFox best.

Well,I want to implement the function in a app like this:
When i use IE to browse pages, I wanna watch the favorites's folder in real time,if i add a page to favorites, the app will create a online bookmark immediately into firefox's bookmarks which has been logined .

How to implement?Have any sapiential ideas in your mind?

Best in javascript or c# language!

Pls share for me ,thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the other's answer in Stack Overflow ,I get the correct skill to operate firefox bookmarks.
Firefox online bookmarks are stored in the sqlite which named "places.sqlite" as a backup file.
In my computer,It is under "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\gyhdax0e.default",xx is represented your windows current username,and the latest folder(gyhdax0e.default) will be another name in your computer(such as abcdef.default).

And then you could operate table "moz_places" and "moz_bookmarks" for your function.But please keep signing in.

Sorry ,I forgot the original url.